# Reusing a xib with a uitableview connected via IBOutlet to a superclass: how is it better add a toolbar with a button only for some subclasses?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xib, uitoolbar, subclassing

I have a xib with a uitableview in it. 
This table is connected via IBOutlet to a ViewController, root of a hierarchy of view controllers.

Now I have to add a toolbar with a button such that it isn't visible in all the views (controlled by subclasses of the root view controller).

How can I do it so that the table resizes properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[urtoolbar setHidden:YES];
```

wherever u want to hide

Comment: When the toolbar is hidden in this way, does the table resize covering the 44/32 pixels of the toolbar? Maybe have I to set properly the autosizing masks?

Comment: yes use mask or u can manually add the toolbar wherever u want to add

Comment: My doubt was if in the second case I had also to set manually the frame of the table too... however I have resolved via XIB, setting properly the autosizing mask. Thank you.

Comment: I have to correct myself: when the toolbar isn't hidden, I don't succeed in seeing all the table rows, scrolling the table.

Comment: when u want to show tool bar just add it to the tableview footer then ur all rows in tableview will be visible. cheers

Comment: At the end, I've used the toolbar of the navigation controller. It works!